# как мне расположить кнопки с помощью grid в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

я делаю прогу для просмотра изображений

Сейчас у меня такой показывает результат:

[image]

но мне нужно, чтобы кнопки 1 и 2 были рядом, т е сверху посередине почти без отступов друг от друга. как это делается?
и еще, как мне сделать так, чтобы картинка не обрезалась при уменьшении окна, а просто уменьшалась.
мой код:

```
from tkinter import *
import PIL
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image

#window options
window = Tk()
window.title('picture viewer(v0.01alpha)')
window.geometry('800x600')
window.config(bg="grey")

for i in range(3):
    window.columnconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=50)
    window.rowconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=50)
#img
pil_image = Image.open("E:/11.jpg")
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)
image_sprite = Label(window, image=image)
image_sprite.grid(row=1, column=1)

#bottons
btn1 = Button(text="1",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",            
             )
btn1.grid(row=0, column=1)
btn11 = Button(text="2",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",            
             )
btn11.grid(row=0, column=2)

btn2 = Button(text="3",           
             background="#555",     
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",            
             )
btn2.grid(row=1, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно положить кнопки в общий фрейм, а этот фрейм уже расположить по сетке над картинкой:

```
common_frame = Frame(window)
common_frame.grid(row=0, column=1)
#bottons
btn1 = Button(common_frame, text="1",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",            
             )
btn1.pack(side=LEFT)
btn11 = Button(common_frame, text="2",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",            
             )
btn11.pack()
```

Также можно через `columnspan=2` задать, чтобы картинка занимала две колонки по ширине, тогда обе кнопки будут над картинкой. Чтобы кнопки были рядом, при их размещении можно указать, чтобы левая кнопка была прижата к правому краю ячейки (`sticky=E`), а правая - к левому (`sticky=W`):

```
image_sprite.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2)

#bottons
btn1 = Button(text="1",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",            
             )
btn1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E)

btn11 = Button(text="2",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",            
             )
btn11.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W)
```